# MDE Access decrypt JDBC

Tags: ms-access, encryption, jdbc, odbc

I want to perform JDBC SQL queries on a MDE Access file.
I've set up the data source ODBC and everything worked well for a MDE file.

Now, I'm working with a newer version of the MDE file, and here is the result:

> java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][Driver ODBC Microsoft Access]
>   Cannont read record. Read authorization unavailable for "tbl_mytable".

If I open the MDE with Access Runtime I am asked for a password, and after leaving a blank password I can see all the data. Of course, "tbl_mytable" does exist inside the database.

Comment: Is this an application database? If not, it shouldn't be an MDE, as MDE's apply only to VBA code. If there's no code, converting to an MDE does nothing at all. Your question confuses me, as you seem to be asking about a data table, but you talk about an MDE. Either you've left out information, or there's something wrong with the setup.

Comment: I'm using the MDE as a data source for my JDBC (Java) application.
I'm not "converting" an MDE, I'm only trying to read it. And I'm reading it by means of a SQL query, but this query responds as written above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you did not make the MDE yourself. As David said, there is no advantage to convert a MDB database to MDE if it is just going to be used as a database file and not an application.

Anyway, it looks like some group security was put in place on the new version of the MDE database you are using.
You need to check with the person who created the original database if they set up security so they can give you the proper username and password needed to access it again.

Once you get the username/password, you can either change your ODBC data source settings or the connection string you are currently using, usually by adding a `"UID=username;PWD=password;"` to it.